# Selenium Chrome Headless failing immediately

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I set "options.headless = True", this fails because the EC condition is never met, as if the menus are not actually being clicked and the page title is not changing.  When not in headless mode, this works absolutely fine and the EC condition is nicely met, implying the top level menu selections worked fine and took me to the right page.....

This is my first attempt at headless mode, but I am assuming it just builds a virtual dom, and so the navigation through the menus should take me to the same page, with the same title as non-headless?

```
class OrganizationsAutomate():

    def __init__(self, driver:ERVAutomate):
        self.driver=driver

    def task_navigate_to_organizations(self):
        print("Navigating to Organizations...")
        print("Clicking Products menu...")
        self.driver.ui.click_nav_menu(selector_type="CSS", selector_text="a.vv-navbar-link",
                                      menu_name="Products", time_to_sleep=2)
        print("Clicking Organizations menu...")
        self.driver.ui.click_nav_menu(selector_type="CSS", selector_text="a.vv-navbar-link",
                                      menu_name="Organizations", time_to_sleep=2)


        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
                EC.title_contains("Organizations")
            )

        except Exception as e:
            print("Do not appear to be on the Organizations page....", e)
            raise e

        print("Navigated to Organizations....")
```

Update: I am having more luck by not maximising the window in Headless mode, and just setting a window size.

```
  def __init__(self, driver_path, url, user_name, user_password, implicit_wait=5, teardown=False):

        self.__driver_path = driver_path
        self.__url = url
        self.__user_name = user_name
        self.__user_password = user_password
        self.__implicit_wait = implicit_wait
        self.__teardown = teardown
        self.__ui = UIInteract(self)

        # add the chrome drive to the path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.__driver_path
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        options.headless = True
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
        options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080");

        # initalise webdriver super class
        super(ERVAutomate, self).__init__(options=options)

        # implicit wait time for finding an element in selenium
        self.implicitly_wait(self.__implicit_wait)
```

Comment: What is your question? How to meet the EC condition while headless?

Comment: Is there any reason, why navigating through menus lands me on a page where the EC is met, but the same process in headless doesn't??

Comment: I'm not sure what the fix is here - have you tried adding optional driver arguments? maybe this will help? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4477

Comment: setting the window size manually rather than trying to maximise seems to have worked. options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080");

Comment: Can you show us your code where you setting the browser options including the screen size?

Comment: @Prophet done...

Answer (score 1):

In headless mode, you can add below args to make it more stable.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
```

or

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
```

also try to put some sleep or delay, having an explicit waits is a way to go with Selenium.

Also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68905227/running-selenium-in-headless-mode-via-linux-causes-errors/68905434#68905434) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this argument as well as headless mode.

```
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```